# Did Vishnu create Krishna?

Tags: mahabharata, vishnu, krishna

Are there any scholars who have supported the view that Krishna was a creation of Vishnu? Or is he identical to Vishnu?

Comment: The puranas refer to Sri Krishna as being an incarnation of Lord Vishnu. What do you mean by 'creation'?

Comment: @SwamiVishwananda Are they the same being or is Krishna a creation of Vishnu?